# Сжатие и упорядочивание CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap, firefox, firefox-extension, стилизация

Имеется файл `bootstrap.css` у которого объем 4 Мб, создатель переборщил явно и сайт просто мертв.
Я взялся оптимизировать сайт и вот проблемка:

Я очистил с помощью расширений `dust me` и `custom css` (Firefox) неиспользуемый CSS, вроде дубликаты остались, но самое главное в файле есть  вида

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
.big-quest {display:none;}
}
@media (max-width: 400px){
.big-quest .pre {color:black;}
}
...............
@media (max-width: 400px){
.ingo div {color:black;}
}
```

Cобственно чем их можно объединить эти `media` в один поток, вот так (сейчас файл 1 Мб):

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
.big-quest {display:none;}
.big-quest .pre {color:black;}
.ingo div {color:black;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме обычной минификации стилей можно использовать и продвинутую - объединять дубликаты классов и @media. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),

    // Минифицирует CSS, объединяет классы. Не ломает CSS, в отличие от cssnano, который, к примеру, может неправильно выставлять z-index
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),

    // Объединяет все @media
    cmq = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),

    // Сокращает CSS-селекторы    
    gs = require('gulp-selectors'),

    // Проставляет вендорные префиксы
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    nib = require('nib');

// Compiling Stylus in CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(cmq())
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

А если совсем делать нечего, то можно еще и селекторы сократить:

```
// Minify selectors
    gulp.task('gs', function() {
        var ignores = {
            classes: ['active', 'menu', 'nav', 'slide', 'error', 'form-control', 'loader', 'showLoader', 'fadeLoader', 'webp', 'wow', 'owl-*', 'i-*'],
            ids: '*'
        };
        gulp.src(['./public/**/*.css', './public/**/*.html'])
            .pipe(gs.run({}, ignores))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    });
```

Кстати, наверняка у вас есть классы, добавляющиеся через JS, поэтому предварительно стоит все такие классы вынести в переменную `ignores`.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно использовать модуль [node-css-mqpacker](https://github.com/hail2u/node-css-mqpacker).

Утилиту можно использовать из [консоли](https://github.com/hail2u/node-css-mqpacker#as-cli-program) (терминала).